# How to use local installed git other than the system built in version?

Tags: git, built-in, bash

I have homebrew installed git. I want to use the local installed git instead of the system built in version in bash.

Brew has created symbolic link to the git package it installed in /usr/local/bin
How should I edit .bash_profile so that I can use the version brew installed other than the one system built in?

Answer (score 0):

You can alias commands to whatever you wish in your `.bash_profile`.

`alias git=/path/to/your/git`

You can use `which git` to tell which git you are in fact using. Remember to `source ~/.bash_profile` or use a fresh terminal to see the change.